# Does $A^TMA = MA^2$ where $A$ is symmetric and $M$ is not necesarily symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, M \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, $A$ is symmetric

Does  $A^TMA = MA^2$ hold regardless of whether $M$ is symmetric?

I have tested some simple examples and have not found a violation. Does a counter example exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A^T=A$ since you ask $A$ to be symmetric. Here is a counterexample:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}, M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

We have $MA^2 = M$ and $A^TMA = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\neq M.$

Comment: For an example with $M$ invertible, we can take $M = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.

Comment: Another example with $M$ invertible is to take $M=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. In that case, we still have $MA^2=M$ but $A^T MA=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\neq M$.

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}4a & 2b \\ 2c & d\end{pmatrix},
$$
but
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}4a & b \\ 4c & d\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

test for 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \mbox{and} \quad
B=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$